# Fill programmatically UISegmentedControl using swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

Is possible fill the values of a `UISegmentedControl` programmatically using swift?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Title", at: 0, animated: true)
segmentedControl.setTitle("Another Title", forSegmentAt: 0)
```

Remember that inserting segments and updating the title should always be done on the main thread. The same goes for adding it to a view if it's not already added to one.

Answer (score 6):

If I am not mistaking, you mean that you want to add segments to "UISegmentedControl" component programmatically, without using the Interface Builder.

Yes, it is possible:

```
// Assuming that it is an "IBOutlet", you can do this in your "ViewController":
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // remove all current segments to make sure it is empty:
        segmentedControl.removeAllSegments()

        // adding your segments, using the "for" loop is just for demonstration:
        for index in 0...3 {
           segmentedControl.insertSegmentWithTitle("Segment \(index + 1)", atIndex: index, animated: false)
        }

        // you can also remove a segment like this:
        // this removes the second segment "Segment 2"
        segmentedControl.removeSegmentAtIndex(1, animated: false)
    }

    // and this is how you can access the changing of its value (make sure that event is "Value Changed")
    @IBAction func segmentControlValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print("index of selected segment is: \(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem, using the solution of @RyuX51
and my code now is:

```
class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var ServicesSC: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ServicesSC.removeAllSegments()


        ServicesSC.insertSegment(withTitle: "Title", at: 0, animated: true)
        ServicesSC.setTitle("Another Title", forSegmentAt: 0)

    }


}
```

Comment: Remember to start your variable with a lowercase letter though and it you don't perform those steps in viewDidLoad (which runs on the main thread), remember to dispatch to main.